Usage of custom passes during transpilation
I am reading a lot about custom passes in the qiskit like
from qiskit.transpiler.passes import (
    Unroll3qOrMore,
    Optimize1qGates,
    CommutativeCancellation,
    ConsolidateBlocks,
    SabreLayout,
    SabreSwap,
   ErrorCorrectionCode,
)

which can help in reducing the depth of the circuit, which I feel is a very important factor for running the circuit on the fake and real hardware.
Below is the sample circuit designed to run on AerSimulator with FakeSherbrooke noise model with the  optimization_level 3 and that really helps in reducing the circuit depth.
import numpy as np

import pdb
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
from qiskit.circuit.library import UCRYGate
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager

from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService, SamplerV2 as Sampler  # Not sue what is the Need for this
from qiskit_aer import Aer
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator

from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import FakeKolkataV2
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import FakeBrisbane, FakeSherbrooke
from qiskit_aer.noise import NoiseModel
import math

backend = FakeSherbrooke()
noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend)
coupling_map = backend.coupling_map

# Some random circuit
#--------------------
num_qubits = 3
data = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
])
angles = [np.pi / 4, np.pi / 2, 3 * np.pi / 4, np.pi]
controls = [0, 1]
target = [2]

qr1 = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, name= 'q')
qc1 = QuantumCircuit(qr1)
qc1.append(UCRYGate(angles), controls + target)
qc1.append(UCRYGate(angles), controls + target)

qr2 = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, name='q')
qc2= QuantumCircuit(qr2)

qc2.unitary(data, qr2, label= 'u')

qc = qc1.compose(qc2, list(range(0, num_qubits)))
qc.measure_all()

#---------------------------------------------------

simulator = AerSimulator(noise_model = noise_model, coupling_map = coupling_map)



pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level = 3)

circuit_opt = pm.run(qc)
print(circuit_opt.draw())
print("Circuit depth: ")
print(circuit_opt.depth())
job = simulator.run(circuit_opt, noise_model = noise_model, shots = 1000)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(circuit_opt)

print(counts)

I am thinking of trying out this custom passes also together with optimization_level 3, but I am not not sure how to do that.
I am using qiskit==1.0.
I just wanted to ask is there any benefit of trying out these passes if we are interested in reducing the circuit depth?
